# Объединение 3х таблиц и выборка данных без дублирования?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, codeigniter

Всем привет!
Ребят, собственно вопрос в следующем.

Есть 3 таблицы.

cities - города

kladr_id - уникальный ключ города

---

manager_cities - города которые закреплены за менеджером

manager_id - ID юзера из таблицы managers

kladr_id - из таблицы cities

---

managers - таблица с данными менеджеров

manager_id - уникальный ключ менеджера

---

Суть в том, что один менеджер может работать в нескольких городах и мне нужно вывести на странице со списком всех менеджеров - их данные. Получается таблица для отображения должна быть:

Имя | Номер телефона | Город(-а)

Помогите пожалуйста написать запрос, чтобы выбрать имя, номер телефона и все города, которые закреплены за менеджером. Простые JOIN'ы не подходят, т.к. я получаю дублирование данных менеджера, если за ним закреплено несколько городов.

Comment: GROUP_BY + GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Решение нашел)) На тостере подсказали)) Ниже ссылка на ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено на тостере, ответ лежит здесь - https://toster.ru/q/527873

Но продублирую еще его сюда:

```
SELECT `m`.`name`, `m`.`phone`, IFNULL(`t`.`cities`, '')
FROM (
SELECT `mc`.`manager_id` AS `manager_id`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`c`.`name`) AS `cities`
FROM `manager_cities` AS `mc`
JOIN `cities` AS `c` ON `c`.`kladr_id` = `mc`.`kladr_id`
GROUP BY `mc`.`manager_id
) AS `t`
RIGHT JOIN `managers` AS `m` ON `m`.`manager_id` = `t`.`manager_id`
```